# ISA Server - how do I set the default domain for web surfers to log on?

Tags: isa-server, web-proxy

A company recently upgraded from Internet Explorer 6 to 7.

Previously, when users were logged in as an account which was not allowed to surf, the ISA Server web proxy would promt them for credentials if they tried, and they could specifiy an anlternative account which was allowed to surf.

The username had a default value, and the default domain portion of this username was the company's (and I guess the ISA Server's) Active Directory domain.

Now the domain portion of the username in the login box is the ISA server's computername.

Is it possible to set the default domain in the login box a web surfer receives, when they first try to surf? As the clients are workgroup machines, ISA server has no way of knowing who the user is without prompting for a username, but seeing the ISA server's name there just comfuses people - it would be better if it were the correct domain, or even blank.

---

This might have more to do with Internet Explorer configuration than with ISA Server.

Answer (score 1):

In ISA Server Management go to the properties of the Internal Network (Configuration -> Networks).
In the "Web Proxy" tab click "Authentication". Now click "Select Domain" and enter the name of the default domain.
I can't test this right now so I'm not 100% sure if it does what you want.

Comment: Right answer to another question - I realize now that this probably has more to do with IE's password-caching behaviour than it does with the ISA web proxy configuration. The "default domain" configuration seems to be used where the ISA server itsself is not a member of that domain, at least as I read it.